# Prove that If $f(x)\to a$ and $f'(x) \to b$ as $x\to +\infty$, then $b = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

In the book of *The elements of Real Analysis*, by Bartle, at page 220, it is asked to show that

> If $f(x)\to a$ and $f'(x) \to b$ as $x\to +\infty$, then $b = 0$

However, I'm having trouble showing the result.

By our assumption, for a given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\delta >0 $ such that $\forall x > M$, $$|f(x) - a| < \epsilon,$$ and 
$$|\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - b| < \epsilon$$ for $0 < |h| < \delta.$

However, (by observing $x+h > x > M$), I get 
$$-2\epsilon / h - b<|f'(x) - b| < 2\epsilon / h - b,$$ which does not let me do anything because of that $h$ in the denominator of $\epsilon$. So my question is, how can we prove this result?

Comment: If $b>0$ then $f$ eventually lies above a line of positive slope $b/2$. If $b<0$ then $f$ eventually lies below a line of negative slope $b/2$. In either case, $f$ tends to $\pm\infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Thus the only way $f$ can tend to $a$ is if $b=0$.

Comment: @nullUser Thanks for you answer. However, in somewhat similar whats, I can see the result intuitively, too, and what I can't see is that how to deal with those epsilons, so I would really appreciate you could post your answer/comment by supporting it with a rigorous mathematical proof.

Comment: Mean value theorem is your friend here. Try it on the difference $f(x+1)-f(x)$.

Comment: To do that, I need to choose $h = 1$, but that would require $\delta > 1$, but for a given $\epsilon > 0$, I cannot guarantee that.

Comment: Here's a little intuition to go with it. If $f$ tends to a certain fixed number, $a$, as $x$ goes to infinity, we can say that $f'$ goes to $0$ at infinity since if it didn't there would be no way that $f \to a$.

Comment: If you like I can put in a proof by contradiction?

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId It would be nice actually.

Comment: Why do you need $h=1$? Your approach has nothing to do with mean value theorem. So don't mix your approach with what I suggested in the comments.

Comment: @ThisIsNotAnId's comment (2017-12-21 07:02:15Z) is wrong - $f\to a$ by itself does not imply $f'\to 0.$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh See the answer that I have posted after your suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct me if wrong :

1)$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) =a$:

Let $\epsilon$ be given .

There exists an $M$, real, such that for $x\ge M $

$|f(x)-a| \lt \epsilon.$

2) MVT:

Consider $h \gt 0$, $h$ fixed.

$hf'(t) = f(x+h) - f(x)$, with

$x \lt t \lt x+h$.

Let $x \gt M$.

$h|f'(t)| = |f(x+h) -f(x)| =$

$ |(f(x+h) -a) -(f(x) -a)| \le$

$|f(x+h) -a| +|f(x)-a| \lt 2\epsilon.$

Recall : $x \lt t\lt x+h:$

$ x \rightarrow \infty$ implies $t \rightarrow \infty$ :

$h \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} |f'(t)|= h|b| \le 2\epsilon.$

This  implies;

$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}|f'(t)|=|b|= 0.$

Note: If $|b| \not=0$ we get a contradiction by choosing $h$, an independent parameter, sufficiently large.

Comment: İt needs to be $x \lt t \lt x+h$

Comment: Even though the rest of the proof is OK, and it is constructed in the way that I was looking, the organisation of the lines makes the answer hard to read.

Comment: Note that, if you do not organise your answer, I cannot accept it.

Comment: Thanks. The typo is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand the diversity of the answers, I'm going to post the proof suggested by @ParamanandSingh

Let for a fixed $x\in \mathbb{R}$, consider the interval $(x, x+1)$. By MVT, $\exists c \in (x, x+1)$ s.t
$$\frac{f(x+1) - f(x)}{1}  = f'(c).$$

Now if we let $x\to +\infty$, $c\to +\infty$, and the difference $$f(x+1) - f(x) \to 0,$$ hence
$$f'(c) \to b\quad as \quad c\to +\infty$$
implies $$b = 0$$

QED.

Comment: It's almost correct. Just write that the LHS $f(x+1)-f(x)$ tends to $a-a=0$ and RHS $f'(c) $ tends to $b$ (given in question). So $b=0$ and you are done. This proof is very standard and available in many good textbooks.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Ok, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I think you should write $f'(c) \to b$ and hence $b=0$. Note that $f'(c) $ may never be equal to $b$ (a limit is not necessarily a value attained). So that equal sign might raise some doubts. +1 anyway. And if you haven't noticed so far your answer is the shortest and simplest.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yeah, I have noticed :)

Answer (score 2):

If we assume

$f'(x) \to b \; \text{as} \; x \to \infty, \tag 1$

then we have, for any $\epsilon > 0$, a sufficiently large $M \in \Bbb R$ such that

$b - \epsilon < f'(x) < b + \epsilon \; \text{for} \; x \ge M; \tag 2$

suppose that $b > 0$; then we choose $\epsilon$ so small that

$b - \epsilon > 0; \tag 3$

then

$f(x) - f(M) = \displaystyle \int_M^x f'(s) \; ds \ge \int_M^x (b - \epsilon)\; ds = (b - \epsilon)(x - M), \tag 4$

whence

$f(x) \ge f(M) + (b - \epsilon)(x - M) \to \infty \; \text{as} \; x \to \infty; \tag 5$

likewise, if $b < 0$, we may choose $\epsilon$ such that

$b + \epsilon < 0; \tag 6$

then by an argument similar to the above we have

$f(x) \le f(M) + (b + \epsilon)(x - M) \to -\infty \; \text{as} \; x \to \infty; \tag 7$

in neither case $b > 0$, $b < 0$ does $f(x) \to a$ as $x \to \infty$; thus, we must have

$b = 0. \tag 8$

Comment: Well, even though I know what is integral, and what does geometrically mean, in the book, we haven't covered that, so it would be really nice if your argument is only based on the algebraic manipulations.

Comment: @onurcanbektas:  well, I had no way of knowing what tools you had at your disposal until I read your comment.  I'm not familiar with Bartle's book, an not in a place where I have access to a copy at the moment.

Comment: Of course, I should have notes those kinds of thing in the question, it is my mistake.

Comment: @onurcanbektas:  The mean value theorem approach suggested by Paramanand Singh might hold some promise, but I'm to sleepy right now to put all the details together.

Comment: @onurcanbektas:  not too bad of a mistake!  Anyway, I just went for the mathematical interest of the question since I don't know how your course is set up.  Cheers!

Comment: @onurcanbektas: Integration is only used here to show that if $f'(x)\geq b-\epsilon$ for $x\geq M,$ then $f(x)-f(M)\geq (x-M)(b-\epsilon)$ for $x\geq M,$ which you should be able to prove directly (e.g. by MVT). (And in fact to use integration you need a fairly exotic integral for arbitrary derivatives, like the Henstock-Kurzweil integral.)

Comment: Sorry, ignore the comment about the integral - integrating a bounded derivative is ok by the Lebesgue fundamental theorem of calculus. (When you get to that!)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

As it is pointed out, there is a mistake in this proof, but it can be solved by observing that the difference $f(x+1)- f(x)$ can be arbitrarily small for sufficient large values of $x$.

---

After getting some ideas, it is clear that easiest method is to use the method of contradiction, so I'm going to post my own proof in here.

WLOG, let $f'(x) > 0$ as $x\to +\infty$, then by the lemma $19.3.a$ in Bartle's book, saying that, $\exists h> 0$ s.t for all y satisfying $x< y < x+h$, we have $f(x)< f(y)$. Then let $f(y) - f(x) = \epsilon'$ and choose $2\epsilon < \epsilon'$ so that $\exists M$ and $\forall x > M$, we have 
$$|f(x) - a| <  \epsilon.$$
Since $y > x > M,$ $|f(y)- a| < \epsilon$, hence
$$0 < \epsilon' < |f(y)- f(x)| < 2\epsilon$$, which is a contradiction.
QED

Comment: This isn’t right - your $\epsilon’$ depends on $x,y$ but your $x,y$ depend on $\epsilon’.$ Maybe you can show there is a positive lower bound on $f(x+1)-f(x)$ for sufficiently large $x.$

Comment: @Dap You are right.